# Blackberry - Get current application's ApplicationDescriptor object

Tags: blackberry, versioning

I'd like to get access to my currently running applications applicationDescriptor object.  I want this so that I can get the current version number and, on the initial screen have a title like "MyApp Version x.x.x" where I get x.x.x from the `ApplicationDescriptor.getVersion()`

One way that I've found is to use:

```
ApplicationManager manager = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
ApplicationDescriptor[] descriptors = manager.getVisibleApplications();

//Loop round descriptors then use...
ApplicationDescriptor myApp = manager.getProcessId(descriptors[x]);
```

Using the loop to check all applications seems a bit long winded to me, i'm hoping that there is an easier route.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

```
ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getVersion()
```